# MYSQL Select Where Time Between Returns Rows Older Than Query

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql DB with a table called data,

```
mysql> describe data;
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field | Type                | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| idx   | int(11)             | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| ts    | timestamp           | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| id    | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| value | decimal(10,2)       | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

When I try to select a specific date range, e.g., today, the query returns data that is out of the date range.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM data WHERE ts BETWEEN '2016-11-27 00:11:00' AND '2016-11-29 00:11:00' AND id LIKE '0' OR id LIKE '1' ORDER BY ts ASC LIMIT 10;
+-------+---------------------+----+-------+
| idx   | ts                  | id | value |
+-------+---------------------+----+-------+
| 14117 | 2016-11-12 15:24:16 |  1 |  0.00 |
| 20144 | 2016-11-16 20:03:50 |  1 | 56.00 |
| 20147 | 2016-11-16 20:04:10 |  1 | 52.00 |
| 20150 | 2016-11-16 20:05:10 |  1 | 52.00 |
| 20153 | 2016-11-16 20:06:11 |  1 | 52.00 |
| 20156 | 2016-11-16 20:07:11 |  1 | 52.00 |
| 20159 | 2016-11-16 20:08:17 |  1 | 52.00 |
| 20162 | 2016-11-16 20:09:18 |  1 | 52.00 |
| 20165 | 2016-11-16 20:10:21 |  1 | 52.00 |
| 20168 | 2016-11-16 20:11:27 |  1 | 52.00 |
+-------+---------------------+----+-------+
```

I'm very new to MYSQL so hopefully this is something easy to solve, but I haven't been able to find the solution (not for lack of trying).

Comment: `AND` has a higher order of precedence than `OR`.  For example, the expression **`a AND b OR c`** is equivalent to **`(a AND b) OR c`**. Use parens to specify the order of operations, i.e. **`a AND (b OR c)`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `OR`.  You can use parentheses, or just use `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE ts BETWEEN '2016-11-27 00:11:00' AND '2016-11-29 00:11:00' AND
      id IN (0, 1) 
ORDER BY ts ASC
LIMIT 10;
```